# File creator recognize folder name as a existing file

Tags: python

I wrote a program which can create a folder, file and return if folder/file has been created or not.
For e.g I created a folder in my program called "test" and next when I select file creator on my menu and enter same name - "test" program tells me he recognized that this file already exist but it doesn't really exist.

````py
import os
import sys

#1. creating file

def creatingFile():
    try:
       fileNames = []
       nameOfFile = input("Enter the name of file: ")
       fileNames.append(nameOfFile)
       if open(nameOfFile,"x") and nameOfFile != fileNames:
           print("file created.")
           sys.exit()
    except FileExistsError:
      print("file already exist.")
      creatingFile()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("please enter name of your file!")
        creatingFile()

#2. creating folder
def creatingFolders():
    try:
        while True:
            nameOfFolder = input("Please enter the name of folder: ")
            if nameOfFolder != "":
                creatingFolder = os.mkdir(nameOfFolder)
                print("Your folder has been created.")
                sys.exit()
            else:
                print("You didn't write the name of your folder. You'll be back to the very beginning of folder creator.")
                continue
    except FileExistsError:
        print("Folder already exists.")
        creatingFolders()

def Menu():
    while True:
        choice = input("What you want to create? File or Folder? ")
        if choice == "folder" or choice == "FOLDER" or choice == "Folder":
            creatingFolders()
        if choice == "file" or choice == "FILE" or choice == "File":
            creatingFile()
        if choice == "":
            print("Please select what you want to select!")
            continue

Menu()```
````

Comment: Are you using Windows? If so, that System doesn't support similar named Files and Folders. Just try it by hand, create a folder named "test" and try to create a file with the same name in the same directory. Might be different using *nix Systems.

Comment: @xph Yes, I'm using Windows...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows, you can't create a file and a folder with the same name, so `test` *does* already exist.